# MAXX function not working properly

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I earlier put this question on the SharePoint StackExchange site but it was considered off-topic. Hoping for better luck here.
I have a problem with the DAX MAXX function (with a FILTER), used in my Power BI. It works only sometimes and "partially" in very confusing ways.
I am following this tutorial:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/sharepoint-scenario-build-report
and the example is given there.
I am using this formula:

```
MaxDaysPending = MAXX(
FILTER('Project Requests', 'Project Requests'[Approved]="Pending"),
'Project Requests'[RequestDateAge]
)
```

..to a table that looks like this:

[image]

The problem is this: In Power BI Desktop:

if I run the formula as-is, I am getting the answer "Blank". (Expected: 316)

If I change "Pending" to "Yes", in the formula, it (correctly) gives the answer 553!

If I change "Pending" to "No", it (wrongly) gives the answer 368! (Expected:458).

Likewise: if I change it to MINX, it works correctly only for "Yes".

I have tried to delete the tables and do it all over again; then it works for a while (even for "Pending"), but then after some data
changes in the table or so, it is the same thing again!

Data type of the Approved column is "single line of text". RequestDateAge is a calculated column ( it has its own formula, I omit it here to not clutter this question too much, otherwise it is all described in he given link above)
Any ideas? Anybody else noticed some strange behaviour of his formula? This is completely illogical.

A "theory" I have: is the first formula executed before the RequestDateAge formula has finished, some way, so the end result goes wrong?
EDIT: No, it's not some race-condition. I tried change RequestDateAge to a non-calculated numeric column (like the Id column), but same behaviour!

Comment: It could be extra spaces in your Approved column. A reason you get blank as a result could be your table has `Pending ` with an extra space instead of `Pending`. I would try to trim your first column of extra spaces. That might make your formula work as expected.

Comment: I suspect it's something like @JohnFriel suggested, but if you can post a minimal pbix file that duplicates your problem, I'll take a look.

Comment: @JohnFriel Thank you for valuable answer! No, there is no blank space what I can see! Data is in a SharePoint list, and no space is added.

Comment: @Alexis Thank you! That would be great. How can I lend you my pbix file? E-mail?

Comment: @PerryJ Google Drive, Dropbox, or any similar web service that lets you upload a file.

Comment: @Alexis Of course! Thanks again. The file is 160 kB. Table names are in Swedish. Commas are replaced with semicolons, as the standard apparently is for the non-US version. You can get it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19bsl25DrTd40X3pkF1r3ZJDG-iFNXCqO

Comment: @PerryJ Your file looks a bit different, but I did notice that you are using `EstimatedDays` in your measure rather than `RequestDateAge` as above. Other than that, it works like I would expect it to.

Comment: @Alexis O yes, that's correct! I forgot to change back to RequestDateAge. As I mention, I switched to some other numeric columns to see if the problem persists! So you do mean that it works for you? After you change semicolons to commas???

Comment: @PerryJ One more thing: you have a Report Level Filter of `Status = "Completed"`. Try removing that filter and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: @Alexis Great! It works!!! So that was the problem? I did never add that f*# filter myself! I am very grateful for showing me this,
and I have truly learned something. Thank you for taking your time! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check your relationships. Sounds like a bad join.

Alternatively, wrap 'Project Requests' in an ALL.

```
MaxDaysPending = MAXX(
FILTER(ALL('Project Requests'), 'Project Requests'[Approved]="Pending"),
'Project Requests'[RequestDateAge]
)
```

Comment: Thank you Frosty, but Alexis solved this for me, see comments above, it was a filter that shouldn't be there!